# has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement AD HOC iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, key-value-store, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I'm having trouble with iCloud key value store.
I currently have a core data synced by iCloud working, but I cannot get K-V Store to work
I'm getting:

```
com.domain.appname has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
```

com.domain.appname is the format of my appid, masked for privacy.

This has been around for a while, and I've seen people having this issue and when reinstalling the app the issue is gone, but that won't apply to me. Don't know why.

My entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.domain.appname</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.domain.appname</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.domain.appname</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If you need anything else just ask, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[this link](http://dhilipsiva.com/2012/07/24/xcode-could-not-launch-app-no-such-file-or-directory-error.html) worked for me. Try this.
Reinstall the app as well as quit the xcode and restart the device.
It will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ill try it out and come back! EDIT: Nope, it did not work.. Still same issue

Answer (score 1):

Simply, the error is saying that the **com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier "Key"** is missing from the entitlement file which had generated when you enabled iCloud in capabilities. Follow the steps in the screenshot I attached:

or 1. just go to the entitlement file and right click on any row and choose Show Raw Keys/Values

2. When you hover over Entitlement File row (at the top), a plus button will appear.
3. Click it and drop down list will appear, choose com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier and for the value just copy and paste this ***$(AppIdentifierPrefix)YOUR_BUNDLE_ID***
4. Clean. Build. And Enjoy.

[image: Entitlement file screen shot]